# Does routing through angular make the server faster instead of routing through express?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

So I am making a web application and I was wondering if I did routing through client side java script (Angular) make my application faster. My thinking is that if I were to do routing through Angular, then it would reduce get requests on my Node server. I am pretty new to the whole full stack thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes As Angular Creates SPA (Single Page Application) ie the app will load only once. This speed up the app in following ways:

1. All major resources like main javascript, css files are loaded only once.
2. partial updatation will be the on the change of routing.

To  reduce multiple get request you can

1. combine all javascript files into single file and css into single file by using (Grunt or gulp) .
2. combine all html, css and javascript file into one file with (Webpack).

But server side routing will be lot more expensive in terms of performance.

Answer (score 1):

I think the short answer is **not necessarily**.

Whether you put the routing logic on the client or server side, the same amount of files still has to be served to the client at some point. So the speed (I assume you mean load time) wouldn't be affected by your decision of where to put the routing logic.

On the server you would need at least some "routing" logic to determine what files are served, but I would put the core routing logic on the client side, seeing as angular has features built exactly for this.